# MVC ajax call not passing parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app that I do ajax calls to but I now need to do a post and pass a json object.

I can't seem to get to the web method that passes the jsonString.

I have an ajax call that does a post:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     global: false,
     url: uri,
     data: "{image:testit}",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
        json = data;
     },
     error: function (err) {
        console.log('Issue with ajaxPostCallForJson - err: ' + err);
        reject('Issue with ajaxPostCallForJson - err: ' + err);
     }
  });
```

The web methods are:

```
  [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
  public string updateAttachmentToServer() 
  {
     string result = string.Empty;
     return result;
  }

  [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
  public string updateAttachmentToServer(string jsonStringWorkIssues)
  {
     string result = string.Empty;
     return result;
  }
```

My routings are:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

It goes to the method that has no parameter but not the one that does, even though my routings have one with a parameter.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

OK,

I changed the Routing to the following so that the parameter name matches the routing and the ajax call:

```
  [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
  public string updateAttachmentToServer(string image)
  {
     string result = string.Empty;
     return result;
  }
```

I added a new routing to handle the new image name:

```
       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "ActionApi2",                                    // Route name  
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{image}",      // URL w/ params  
          defaults: new { image = RouteParameter.Optional }  // Param defaults  
       );
```

The ajax call was changed to:

```
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     async: false,
     global: false,
     url: uri,
     data: { image: '10'},     //"{ modelCode:\"" + $(this).attr('data-model') + "\", vdcCode:\"" + $(this).attr("data-vdc") + "\" }",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function (data) {
        json = data;
     },
     error: function (err) {
        console.log('Issue with ajaxPostCallForJson - err: ' + err);
        reject('Issue with ajaxPostCallForJson - err: ' + err);
     }
  });
```

But it still goes to the first method - the one with no parameters.

Answer (score 2):

```
data: "{image:testit}",
```

should be

```
data: {image:testit},
```

Comment: I tried that and it still goes to the method without the parameter.  I tried changing the parameter name to "image" to see if that was the issue, but it wasn't.  I also tried delete the line with "contenttype" as I saw that as an issue in another question.

Comment: I made a few changes as shown above but it still doesn't pass any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

1) dataType: "json", // its mean server return data type

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
 public string updateAttachmentToServer(string image)
 {
   string result = string.Empty;
   return result;
  // here return should be json , instead of string
}
```

2 ) Make sure Url of webapi

3) contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", its mean data type send to server , change your data to json first then send to server

```
 data: JSON.stringify({ image: '10'}),
```

Comment: I tried the JSON.stringify, but it still didn't go to the one with the parameter.

Comment: Check with default api config setting .. no need change routing

Comment: What you are using MVC OR WebApi ?

Comment: I am using both.  I am using MVC for my main page and do ajax calls so that my page doesn't reload.

Comment: try to add traditional : true

Comment: I did find that if I use MVC by itself, calling a method in the controller, it works fine.  But if I try an ajax call to a web API controller, it doesn't.  It works fine if you are not passing parameters but when we pass parameters, it ignores them and just call the method without the parameters.